# Number of triangles in tripartite graph with $\epsilon$-uniform sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, triangles

Consider all the tripartite graphs $V_1,V_2,V_3,E$, $|V_1|=|V_2|=|V_3|=n$ with $\epsilon$-uniform pairs (i.e. all 3 pairs of vertex sets are $$\epsilon$-uniform$), and a given edge densities $d(V_1,V_2)=d_{12},d(V_1,V_3)=d_{13},d(V_2,V_3)=d_{23}$.

I know that on average, each of these graphs has $n^3\cdot d_{12}d_{23}d_{34}$ triangles. Can I bind the deviation that a specific graph can have from that number (i.e. the difference between the real number in that graph to the average number)?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in [this great post](https://matheuscmss.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/applications-of-szemeredis-regularity-lemma-triangle-removal-lemma-roths-theorem-corners-theorem-and-graph-removal-lemma/) in "Disquisitiones Mathematicae" blog,
in the first section "Triangle removal lemma".
There, a lower bound is provided, but a similar upper bound can be deduced using the same techniques.